# Git dividing branch for new mechanic and updating both of them automatically

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, branching-and-merging

I have a project, and I want to try a new mechanic by modifying the old one. However, I would like git to keep Auto updating old and new mechanics branches until I'm satisfied with choosing one of them after seeing the data.

As an example:
Assume I have a script called "character mechanics" which has moving and jumping functions of the character.

```
void Move(){
//I am moving at the speed of 5
}

void Jump(){
//jumping without checking stamina
}
```

and a script called Common Mechanics which includes other stuff.

So, this was my main branch, I will create a branch called "newJump". In the newJump jump function of the character mechanics changed to this;

```
void Move(){
//I am moving at the speed of 5
}

void Jump(){
//jumping with checking stamina
}
```

After this point whenever I change something in main branch such as changing common mechanics or adding new script or even changing the Move function, I want git to apply the same changes to newJump branch as well.
However, I want to keep out jumping mechanics from the changes.

For example, if I do some changes in main branch;

changes on main branch:

```
void Move(){
//I am moving at the speed of 10
}

void Jump(){
//jumping without checking stamina
}
```

after merging this with newJump branch, I want it to look like this:

```
void Move(){
//I am moving at the speed of 10
}

void Jump(){
//jumping with checking stamina
}
```

Is it possible? Do I need to keep updating both branches manually?

Comment: That sounds like a regular `git merge`. Is it not working?

Comment: it gives conflict on character mechanics script which makes it not auto

Comment: If there are conflicts, you need to tell Git which text you want. Nothing Git can do, it doesn't know how the correct result would look like. Your showcase might be simple, but Git has to work for general cases too.

Comment: I just want git to ignore some lines on the script, so it won't create a conflict when I merge. So I can keep branches 2 different mechanics updated without manually changing one of them every time

Comment: You cannot ignore _lines_. The smallest entity in Git is a file, but it will try to the best of its ability to merge the lines of two files. If it cannot automatically merge them, it will ask the human to resolve the conflicts. Better have a human do it manually than to merge incorrectly but automatically.